# According to Arminian Protestants, who can forgive sin or withhold forgiveness?

Tags: protestantism, forgiveness, arminianism, church-offices

> "If you forgive the sins of any, they are forgiven them; if you withhold forgiveness from any, it is withheld." 
>  (John 20:23)

The [Power of the Keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_the_Keys) is a Catholic (and, IIUC, Lutheran) doctrine that only certain individuals — particularly and approximately, those serving as "Priests" (i.e. pastors in Protestant terminology) — have certain abilities.

In John 20:23, Jesus makes it plain that *someone* has the ability to forgive and to withhold forgiveness. Some interpret this (along with other scripture, e.g.  Matthew 16:19, Matthew 18:18 and 1 Corinthians 5:1-5) to mean that this ability is "special" somehow to priests/pastors. It is from this same doctrine (IIUC) that we get the idea of excommunication, which is similarly granted to specific "offices" within the Church.

Protestants, of course, reject many Catholic teachings.

What I would like to know is, **who, according to Arminian Protestants, has the power specified in John 20:23**? Who (if anyone; see also [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30258)) can forgive sins or withhold forgiveness? Is it *any* Christian, or only pastors? Or some other distinction? (For bonus points, is excommunication a thing?)

I am asking about *Arminian* (or at least, non-Anglican, non-Lutheran, and non-Calvinist) Protestants specifically, as the answer is obviously different for the excluded groups. (Well, maybe not for Calvinists, but their ideas on predestination muddy things IMHO.)

---

While the (first) linked question is related, it doesn't have much in the way of answers, and, more importantly, doesn't appear answer the more specific "*who* has 'the Keys'" question that I am asking. There are some [other](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/89608) [questions](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/83406) which also appear similar, but aren't clear what group they apply to, aside from [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/89675/53502) which is specifically Lutheran.

Comment: When someone sinned in Corinth Paul urged the whole assembly of the _ekklesia_ to remove the wickedness and he made it clear that he would be with them in spirit, when they did so. 1 Corinthians 5: 1-5. The question is broader than just the text quoted. But up-voted +1, nevertheless as it is a valid inquiry.

Comment: @NigelJ, certainly, and I don't mean to imply otherwise. John 20:23 is... call it the "poster child" verse for the Power of the Keys concept. I use it as convenient context, but yes, I'm asking about the concept in general. I'll try to clarify...